# Are these descriptions of batch gradient descent algorithm conflicting each other?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gradient-descent

The first one is from [Andrew Ng](https://class.coursera.org/ml-005/lecture/11)

[image]

The second one is from [Francis Bach](http://www.ann.jussieu.fr/~plc/bach2012.pdf)
[image]

I might be a little confused, but why is there a summation of partial derivatives in the second description and none in the first one? Are they talking about the same thing after all?

Comment: The summation is the "batch" part, meaning that you use all the $n$ training samples. This is just what Andrew Ng says here: http://class.coursera.org/ml-003/lecture/view?lecture_id=105 (minute 3:30). Your link does not lead to the actual source of the first formulation, which is just an update step for one single element for a 2D problem.

Comment: Ah, I see it: in the notation used by Ng, $J$ is a cost function which includes the summation, see again here http://class.coursera.org/ml-003/lecture/view?lecture_id=105, minute 7:30.